# TortoiseSVN keeps showing TortoiseMerge when I want TortoiseDiff

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Several times in recent days, I have used TortoiseSVN to 'Show Log', navigated to the revision I want, double-clicked a file to show changes to that file, and instead of the nice diff window I usually get

[image: TortoiseDiff]

I'm receiving a blank TortoiseMerge window:

[image: TortoiseMerge]

This has happened a couple of times but I don't know the solution. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that didn't fix it so I blew away my VM and got a new one. What could be going wrong? I have Tortoise 1.8.2.24708.

Comment: I completely don't understand what you are asking about. While irrelevant to your question, I see that you use TortoiseSVN 1.8.2. It is outdated; upgrade to TortoiseSVN 1.9.3, the latest one.